# Can a Plotly visualization show separate Legends for Color, Symbol, Size, etc.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

Like ggplot2, can we have separate legends for Color, Symbol, etc. for a Plotly Express visualization?

```
from pydataset import data
import plotly.express as px
mtcars = data('mtcars')
mtcars.am = mtcars.am.astype('category')
mtcars.gear = mtcars.gear.astype('category')

plt = px.scatter(mtcars, x = 'mpg', y='qsec', color ='disp', symbol = 'am', size = 'wt')
plt.show()
```

Here, no separate legends are generated.

Also, If one of the legends has continuous value strip, then other legends become invisible.

[image]

Now, compare this with GGPLOT (I have used python package plotnine):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = 'mpg', y='qsec', color ='disp', shape = 'am', size = 'wt')) + geom_point()
```

[image]

So, simple and complete. How can we get an output like this using Plotly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your latest attempt looks pretty good. And personally I don't see the need for the size of legend elements to reflect sizes in the figure itself as long as the details otherwise are clear. Here's a little setup to adjust your `legend` and `colorbar`:

```
fig.layout.legend.y = 1.05
fig.layout.legend.x = 1.035
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.y = 0.35
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
from pydataset import data
import plotly.express as px
mtcars = data('mtcars')
mtcars.am = mtcars.am.astype('category')
mtcars.gear = mtcars.gear.astype('category')

fig = px.scatter(mtcars, x = 'mpg', y='qsec', color ='disp', symbol = 'am', size = 'wt')

fig.layout.legend.y = 1.05
fig.layout.legend.x = 1.035
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.y = 0.35
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I want separate Legends. So, one legend shows colors and another shows symbol.
If I have included a color strip for a continuous variable, then the other legends become invisible.

Comment: @Samit `If I have included a color strip for a continuous variable, then the other legends become invisible.` I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Could you include a more detailed description in the question? Perhaps show it with an image?

Comment: since I could not paste the image here, I have updated in the question itself. Thanks a lot for taking time and looking into it. I am a fan of R. But I am now learning Python because my colleagues are working on Python. My work mostly involve visual stories explanation. Till now, I liked Plotly until I saw a huge drawback which I explained in my question. For data analytics we often need to do multi dimensional analysis. Is there a way out in Plotly or any other visualization package in Python that gets rids of these kind of shortcomings? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Samit Shortcomings? Plotly has no shortcomings, only [happy accidents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Tq5vXk0wTk&ab_channel=JOANNFabricandCraftStores). To answer the very last part of your queston, I'll write up a suggestion that let's you adjust a few elements to make it work for you. When it comes to the rest of the details, I prefer the interactivity and beauty of plotly to all other alternatives any day. I find it *much* easier to adjust the few elements I need in a plotly figure than making a figure from other libraries interactive.