# Group each "graph dimension" in the legend of Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I would like to add to the Plotly "standard legend" produced by `plotly.express` each of the "graph dimensions" grouping together all traces of such characteristics. As it is probably hard to understand what I want to do from the previous description, let me put an example. I have a code that produces a plot using the following line:

```
px.line(
    df,
    x = 'x values',
    y = 'y values',
    color = 'Device specs', # This is what I call "color dimension".
    symbol = 'Device', # This is what I call "symbol dimension".
    line_dash = 'Contact type', # This is what I call "line_dash dimension".
)
```

and the plot looks (for some specific data) like this:

[image]

I want to add below this legend one legend for each "dimension", i.e. one legend for the `color` grouping all the traces of each color, one for the `symbol` and one for the `line_dash`, something like this:

[image]

and, if possible, such that if I click in e.g. contact=dot it toogles the visibility of all the dashed traces together.

Is this possible with Plotly Express?

Comment: You linked this question, can you fix that?

Comment: Haha, yes! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168232/can-a-plotly-visualization-show-separate-legends-for-color-symbol-size-etc/67169416#67169416) is the correct link.

Comment: Answering to your (deleted) question, `plotly.express.scatter` does what I want by default if you use a continuous color scale and markers. However that is a (very) particular case of my question, which is not of use to me in this application. I want to be able to do that in a general case, specifically here using `plotly.express.line` and having 3 "graph dimensions" (discrete color, line dash and symbol).

Comment: So now I have rechecked the question you linked and yes, it seems to be the same. However he seemed to be asking for that very specific case, and accepted an answer that does not answer the question; the answer only shows how to change the size of the color bar so it does not overlap the legend. The accepted answer is indeed more suited for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827165/plotly-how-to-handle-overlapping-colorbar-and-legends). I would thus appreciate if you leave this question open.

Comment: Certainly! Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: do you have some sample data?  I get your plot,  but it's going to be some effort to generate a data set plus answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- generate a data frame that has features that you have defined
- creating core figure is simple - just uses your code
- adding dimensions to legend.  This uses core concept that a legend shows all traces in a figure.  Hence to extend legend,  need additional traces
- traces are built in a **list** comprehension with parameters that match your requirement.  These traces are deliberately given a *y value* that will not be included in y-axes range

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

SIZE = 10
# generate a dataset with all required attributes
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x values": np.tile(np.linspace(0, SIZE - 1, SIZE), SIZE),
        "y values": np.sort(np.random.uniform(1, 1000, SIZE ** 2)),
        "Device": np.concatenate(
            [np.full(SIZE, np.random.choice([52, 36, 34], 1)) for _ in range(SIZE)]
        ),
        "Contact type": np.concatenate(
            [np.full(SIZE, np.random.choice(["dot", "ring"], 1)) for _ in range(SIZE)]
        ),
        "Device specs": np.concatenate(
            [
                np.full(SIZE, np.random.choice(["laptop", "tablet", "console"], 1))
                for _ in range(SIZE)
            ]
        ),
    }
)
df.loc[df["x values"].eq(SIZE - 1), "y values"] = np.nan

# build the standard figure
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="x values",
    y="y values",
    color="Device specs",  # This is what I call "color dimension".
    symbol="Device",  # This is what I call "symbol dimension".
    line_dash="Contact type",  # This is what I call "line_dash dimension".
)

# build additional traces for items wanted in legend
legend_traces = [
    px.line(
        df,
        x="x values",
        y=np.full(len(df), -1000),
        **param["px"],
    ).update_traces(**param["lg"], legendgroup=str(param["px"]))
    for param in [
        {"px": {"color": "Device specs"}, "lg": {"legendgrouptitle_text": "Spec"}},
        {"px": {"symbol": "Device"}, "lg": {"legendgrouptitle_text": "Device"}},
        {
            "px": {"line_dash": "Contact type"},
            "lg": {"legendgrouptitle_text": "Contact type"},
        },
    ]
]

for t in legend_traces:
    fig.add_traces(t.data)

# hide the dummy traces for extra legend entries (given y-value of -1000)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, df["y values"].max()])
fig.update_layout(height=500)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I guess this is not yet implemented in Plotly Express, i.e. I have to do it "by hand". I appreciate your example. Small thing, if you change `y = np.full(len(df), -1000),` to `y = np.full(len(df), float('NaN')),` you don't need to hide any dummy trace as they will be invisible.

Comment: good point... I did build it such that it could be made fully generic by using listcomprehensions and effectively a list of parameters for the legend groups required

Comment: Do you know if it is possible and how to implement the last part of my question? Link the added legend elements to the original traces such that when you click e.g. on laptop it toggles all the traces of type laptop, and so on? I think this should be done using the "legend group" but not sure how to do it.

Comment: with a callback mechanism yes... are you open to using **dash**, possibly `FigureWidget()`

Comment: No, I prefer to keep it simple. For the moment I am using Plotly as (very nice) a replacement for Matplotlib. Thanks anyway.